# when to use nullable short hand and what is the peformance impact, if any?

Tags: c#, nullable

the null-able short hand property

```
public long? id{get;set}
```

what is the incentive of using it, other than if you are reading it from a database, is there a chance the value might be null...?

also, if you want to get the id,

```
 int a = id.value;
```

what is the performance impact on this? and in which situation will you be compelled to use this shorthand. Please share your thoughts on this

Comment: Performance impact is minimal / almost non-existant, a nullable type simply adds the cost of a `bool` to denote if it is null or not. It is also a `struct` so does not put pressure on the GC. The use of nullable types is when you need the logic to define if an item is null (has no value), versus having a default / entered value. Consider the situation where you use the entire range of a type, so there are no values left to denote "the user hasn't entered anything".

Comment: It seems you already found an incentive. Do you expect an exhaustive use case of cases where you might not have the value of a value type?

Comment: (Off the top of my head: optional numeric or date time fields in a form. Optional any situation where you're getting a value type from somewhere else.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is the direct check if is null or no

```
long v = id ?? v2; //if id is null v will get the v2 value
```

And the performance is pratically the same of a normal one